# Connecting to MSSQL server using Cpanel

Tags: sql, sql-server, laravel, cpanel

I am currently in the process of moving over my locally made laravel application to the web. I am using cpanel for shared hosting. Currently my app used three different databases. The normal MySQL database, a microsoft azure database, and a microsoft sql server database. Currently I am able to connect to 2 of the three databases as I cant connect to the MSSQL database. When I attempt to connect to the database I get the following error:

```
[ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (SQL: SELECT * FROM tblGlue)
```

I know that something is going wrong before it tries to authenticate the user as I can change my username or a password to a non-existent user and I get the same error. When I connected to my azure database I had to use the stored procedure sp_set_firewall_rule to allow the IP of my website to access the databse. Is there something like this that I have to do for MSSQL as that's the only thing I can think of that's different. Here is the configuration for the database.

```
'sqlsrv' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => "xxxx",
            'port' => "1433",
            'database' => "TEAM",
            'username' => "xxxx",
            'password' => "xxxxx",
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
        ],
```

Also when I run DB::connection("sqlsrv")->getDatabaseName() I get a good result. However DB::connection("sqlsrv")->getPdo() gives the same error.
I'm thinking that the server is blocking the IP of my website somehow. Any ideas on how I can fix this. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Just make sure that your local instance of SQL Server allows SQL authentication.

Comment: @Zhorov if it didn't would it allow me to connect locally. Because while I was working on the app locally, I could connect to the database without a problem

Comment: @Zhorov I think it does. As when I log into MS SQL management studio I use SQL Server Authentication to log in

Comment: Avoid idle connections, recheck retry logic and check if you have wrong DNS configured, ports outbound, ISP provider, proxy or redirections

Answer (score 0):

Avoid to use `Select *` and return just needed rows. Try increasing the connection timeout value. I recommend using a connection timeout of at least 30 seconds.
Use parameter `login_timeout`.

```
'mssql' => [
  'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
  'host' => 'CDBSQLSERVER',
  'database' => 'MyDatabase',
  'username' => 'XXXX',
  'password' => 'XXXX',
  'charset' => 'utf8',
  'prefix' => '',
  'login_timeout' => YOUR_TIMEOUT
]
```

Further you can Verify or copy the connection string for your database from the Azure portal.

[image]
Use UID in place of username.

Your client can assist in a diagnosis by logging all errors it encounters. You might be able to correlate the log entries with error data that SQL Database logs itself internally.